# Reduce image color count without lowering to 256 / index color?

Tags: colors

I have a JPEG image that has a very high color count. I *explicitly* can nor want to reduce the color count down to 256 (or indexed color) though I do want to reduce the color count in general.

How do I reduce the color count to still be 8-bit / non-indexed without using effects like blur?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping to map similar colors to each other and this seems to sort of count to an extent.

Photoshop → Image → Adjustments → Match Color → Color Intensity

This generally lowers the number of colors by turning everything grey (100% is normal, 0 is grey scale only).

It'll reduce the file size though it's not exactly what I'm looking for. It may be worthwhile for someone else. I'm still open to answers though. If an image has lets say 2,050 colors I'd like to reduce it by 200-500 colors until just before it perceptually begins to degrade. Just like Save for Web in Photoshop only above the 256 index color limitation for GIF and (lower colored) PNG formats.